# plot() in R - how to shade an area between two vertical lines?

Tags: r, plot, colors

how can I shade the area in the plot that is marked with the two red verticle lines? (The shaded area must not be limited by the curve)

```
plot(1980:2019,y,type="l")
abline(v=1990,col="red")
abline(v=2001,col="red")
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I think this kind of thing is much easier to do with ggplot.

Comment: thanks for your answer. COuld you explain how that works with ggplot? That would be great..

Comment: Sure, can you share a bit of you data? It make the helping easier

Comment: you can put some of what you use in the post and even better , give an example of the desired output as well

Comment: Sure. 
x<-1980:2019
y<-runif(40,0,1)
abline(v=1990,col="red")
abline(v=2001,col="red")

and I want to shade the area between the two red verticle lines 

Does that help?

Comment: haha yes that was by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use ggplot doing this:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    df = cbind(1980:2019,runif(40,0,1))
    df=as.data.frame(df)
    ggplot() + 
      geom_rect(aes(xmin=1990, xmax=2001,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf), fill='red', alpha= 0.3)+
      geom_line(data=df,aes(x=V1,y = V2), color = "darkred")+
      theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use `rect` as shown.  Lower values of alpha give more transparency.

```
y <- 1980:2019
plot(y, y)

rect(xleft = 1999, xright = 2001, ybottom = par("usr")[3], ytop = par("usr")[4], 
  border = NA, col = adjustcolor("blue", alpha = 0.3))
```

[image: screenshot]